# Rails/Paypal - how to redirect end-user to paypal website to enter credit card details as payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

this may be asked many times but i need a guiding in rails specifics.

i want to redirect my user to paypal site where they can either key in their paypal account detail login, or choose credit card payment (allowed even without paypal), and redirect back to my site once transaction details key in done in paypal site.

In tutorial here:
https://launchschool.com/blog/paypal-payments-with-credit-cards

it still redirect users back to owner's website to key in credit card details when they chose to pay through credit card in paypal site. this might garner issues on PCI compliance and users might not trust a new startup.

have been searching for proper tutorials but can't find a really proper one.
even guides from paypal site is a mess from my point of view.
and the rails paypal sdk gem, i have no understanding at all with no proper guiding which is very frustrating.

i hope someone could advise me on this with proper rails integration.

thanks,